# TRAC - change css but being overwrote on page load

Tags: css, trac, bitnami

Does anyone know how I can change a css files like roadmap.css for trac? I figured out where the file is but when I modify it, the modification is overwrote on page load/refresh.

Example of where my roadmap css is – x:\xx\xx\BitNami Trac Stack projects\.egg-cache\Trac-0.12.1-py2.5.egg-tmp\trac\htdocs\css\roadmap.css

I would like to add some different classes for the milestone graph like

table.progress td.promote { background: #dcefdc}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the existing stylesheets, add your custom styles to a new stylesheet and link it into your pages.  Your custom styles should override the built-in styles.  See [TracInterfaceCustomization](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization) for more info and [CookBook/SiteStyleCss](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CookBook/SiteStyleCss) for examples.

Comment: Thanks. For this, I renamed E:\Documents and Settings\xxx\BitNami Trac Stack projects\xxx\templates\site.html.sample to site.html and added <style>
 table.progress td.promote { background: #dcefdc}
 </style>

Comment: For a single style modification that works fine, but if you are doing very many it will be easier to have site.html link to a stylesheet than to add them all inline.